# Taking a loop's results and put them into new arrays (in PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Sorry for the beginner question.

Here I have 4 arrays with names, hair colour, ages and heights and then I used a for loop to get a result  that takes one attribute from each array:

```
$names = array('zed', 'sam', 'dean', 'moss', 'jen');

$hairs = array('red', 'blonde', 'brown', 'black', 'auburn');

$ages = array('22', '25', '26', '29', '35');

$heights = array('184', '156', '171', '122', '168');



for ($i = 0 ; $i<=5; $i ++)

{


echo $names[$i] . " " . $hairs[$i] . " " . $ages[$i] . " " . $heights[$i];

echo "\n";

}
```

But now I need to create 5 people out of those arrays, each person taking one attribute from each. Each person should be a NEW array.

I am brand new to coding and I have tried so many ways to do this over the past few days but nothing is working!

Comment: what you have done is right. Do you want to make the names go into an array than just printing on the scree?

Comment: @Rinsad Yes, I need each result to now be put into new arrays, one array per person. This is where I am stuck now

Comment: One array per person or each person is a record in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i<=5; $i ++) {
    $person[] = array("name"=> $names[$i],
        "hair"=>$hairs[$i],
        "age"=>$ages[$i],
        "height"=>$heights[$i]
    );
}
```

after for loop use this for output

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($person);
```

Its very helpful for you.
Thanks

Comment: Missing an parenthesis :

Comment: I've added the missing paranthesis and semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array called $names and push your new names to it as follows

```
$names = array();

for ($i = 0 ; $i<=5; $i ++)
{
 $names[] = $names[$i] . " " . $hairs[$i] . " " . $ages[$i] . " " . $heights[$i];
}
print_r($names);
```

Comment: as a concataneted string?? That's what you'd recommend to a new learning programmer?

Comment: what if the OP then needs the hair color of dean? The result here might be ok for displaying, but to a learning programmer we should at least propose _good_ code to learn from.